# What are the required fields to create user through social media login?

Tags: 7, users

I want to integrate **Social Media Login** (which is not a module name, I am going to integrate the [HybridAuth Social Login](http://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) module) in my website. So that I just want to know the required (by our website Drupal signup) fields in social sign up process.

I guess that username and email are required, but is the password required?

Answer (score 1):

For Social Media Login Password field is not required. Only Username, Email-ID is required. After register with with social media login, Your account is pending for approval by the site administrator. You will receive an email once your account has been approved and you can then login with your Google account.

Comment: but in users table password field are filled with some hash value for my social media logged in user..user did't update when registering

Comment: What settings you configured in "Account creation settings" for 
OneAll Social Login?